# How use npmjs SortedSet library on html?

Tags: javascript, html, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu2E0.jpg)Library web site

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sorted-set

could not use the library, in a simple html project.

```
<script src="path/to/sorted-set.min.js"></script>
<script>

    const set = new SortedSet({ comparator: function (a, b) { return b - a } })
    set.insert(5)
    set.insert(3)
    set.insert(2)
    set.remove(3)

    const yes = set.contains(2)
    
</script>
```

[Error Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufkga.jpg)

---

### FOR COMMENTS

1. [These are the files that I downloaded from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUuzo.jpg)
2. [This is the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t92XL.jpg)

Comment: Download the library then replace `path/to` with the library `path` for example `C:/users/sorted-set`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work anyway, it gives an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: SortedSet is not defined"

Comment: Edit your question and add your files and folder structure (specially where the `sorted-set.min.js` is)  so we can help.

Comment: Friends at the bottom of the question, I added two images.

Comment: The file in the first image, I downloaded from github. Maybe I downloaded the necessary libraries from the wrong place.

Comment: The question is that, I do not know where to download the necessary libraries for the html project, and I need an example of use

Comment: @JS_INF You can download libraries to your computer. And check this class for workability.

Comment: You are using it in node ? or Static Html?

Comment: @Divyanshu Sah I am using this in static HTML. I have no experience with NodeJs. And I don't want to know NodeJs

Comment: First thing first, You've included the wrong path `path/to/sorted-set.min.js` enter your exact HTML path for `sorted-set.js` directory. That'll work perfectly.

Comment: Right Click on `sorted-set.js` on your PC, for getting the directory if you couldn't understand. and don't paste the whole directory. Make sure to match it with your current working directory.I've seen your URL : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUuzo.jpg and you've downalded from Github.

Comment: @Divyanshu Sah
In my opinion, I've tried everything. Please someone check on your computer to see if this class works.